# How to instantiate Capsule to always be facing another GameObject regardless of Capsule's world position?

Tags: unity

I have the following line of code:

`Instantiate(capsulePrefab, GameObject.Find("BlueCube(Clone)").transform.position + transform.right * 1f - transform.up * 1f - transform.forward * 1f, (Quaternion.Euler(0f, 135, 0f)));`

Basically, I am instantiating a capsule `capsulePrefab` at the location of another prefab `BlueCube(Clone)` but 1 unit to the right, behind, and down.

That much works fine (it does spawn in the correct position). But on top of this, I am trying to make it so that `capsulePrefab` spawns facing towards `BlueCube(Clone)` prefab.

Instead, what happens is that `capsulePrefab` only spawns facing `BlueCube(Clone)` if `BlueCube(Clone)` is in certain world positions,  like so:

[image]

Therefore, how can it be coded that when `capsulePrefab` spawns, it always spawns facing `BlueCube(Clone)`?

Comment: By "facing" you mean "pointing its red local transformation arrow at"? The red (x+) arrow is more conventionally used to represent the "right" side of an object, while the blue (z+) arrow is used to denote the "front"/"facing" direction. That's why `transform.forward' points along the object's local z+ and `Vector3.forward == (0, 0, 1)` Are you sure you want to deviate from that convention?

Comment: Sorry, that's right-  I was confused about what which axis denotes `facing` direction. I am trying to get it to conventionally face towards `BlueCube(Clone)` upon Instantiation.

Comment: You can use  transform.LookAt(target) after instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity, you can make an object look at an object or point in space with the [`transform.LookAt()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) function, for example:

`capsule.transform.LookAt(blueCube.transform.position);`
or
`capsule.transform.LookAt(blueCube.transform);`

If you want the capsule to *always* face the cube, even if the cube or capsule moves around, you can use a [Look At constraint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LookAtConstraint.html).

Basic questions like this can be answered with a simple web search.

**EDIT:**
As to DMGregory's comment, if you only want to yaw (rotate on the global Y axis) without any pitch or roll, do this:

```
var position = blueCube.transform.position;
position.y = capsule.y; // Prevent looking up or down
capsule.transform.LookAt(position);
```